# Convert Cheat Engine base address

Tags: pointers, memory, autoit, cheat-engine, base-address

I found a memory address and used Cheat Engine's pointer scan to get referring pointers. To use it in a script I need a base address, which is `[game.exe+009274]`. How to convert this to an address for use in AutoIt script?

I use [NomadMemory.au3 UDF](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/28351-improved-_mem-udfs/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written 2 function some time ago. One to load all the modules loaded with the process and one to get the base address of the module you need.
Both might be handy here.

```
Local $iPID = WinGetProcess("app.exe")
Local $sLoadedModules = _ProcessGetLoadedModules($iPID)
Local $My_dll = _MemoryModuleGetBaseAddress($iPID, "My.dll")

For $i = 0 To UBound($sLoadedModules) - 1
    ConsoleWrite($sLoadedModules[$i] & @LF) ; find your process here
Next
ConsoleWrite($My_dll & @LF)


Func _ProcessGetLoadedModules($iPID)
    Local Const $PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
    Local Const $PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010
    Local $aCall, $hPsapi = DllOpen("Psapi.dll")
    Local $hProcess, $tModulesStruct
    $tModulesStruct = DllStructCreate("hwnd [200]")
    Local $SIZEOFHWND = DllStructGetSize($tModulesStruct) / 200
    $hProcess = _WinAPI_OpenProcess(BitOR($PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, $PROCESS_VM_READ), False, $iPID)
    If Not $hProcess Then Return SetError(1, 0, -1)
    $aCall = DllCall($hPsapi, "int", "EnumProcessModules", "ptr", $hProcess, "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($tModulesStruct), "dword", DllStructGetSize($tModulesStruct), "dword*", "")
    If $aCall[4] > DllStructGetSize($tModulesStruct) Then
        $tModulesStruct = DllStructCreate("hwnd [" & $aCall[4] / $SIZEOFHWND & "]")
        $aCall = DllCall($hPsapi, "int", "EnumProcessModules", "ptr", $hProcess, "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($tModulesStruct), "dword", $aCall[4], "dword*", "")
    EndIf
    Local $aReturn[$aCall[4] / $SIZEOFHWND]
    For $i = 0 To UBound($aReturn) - 1

        $aCall = DllCall($hPsapi, "dword", "GetModuleFileNameExW", "ptr", $hProcess, "ptr", DllStructGetData($tModulesStruct, 1, $i + 1), "wstr", "", "dword", 65536)
        $aReturn[$i] = $aCall[3]

    Next
    _WinAPI_CloseHandle($hProcess)
    DllClose($hPsapi)
    Return $aReturn
EndFunc   ;==>_ProcessGetLoadedModules

Func _MemoryModuleGetBaseAddress($iPID, $sModule)
    If Not ProcessExists($iPID) Then Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
    If Not IsString($sModule) Then Return SetError(2, 0, 0)
    Local $PSAPI = DllOpen("psapi.dll")
    Local $hProcess
    Local $PERMISSION = BitOR(0x0002, 0x0400, 0x0008, 0x0010, 0x0020)
    If $iPID > 0 Then
        Local $hProcess = DllCall("kernel32.dll", "ptr", "OpenProcess", "dword", $PERMISSION, "int", 0, "dword", $iPID)
        If $hProcess[0] Then
            $hProcess = $hProcess[0]
        EndIf
    EndIf
    Local $Modules = DllStructCreate("ptr[1024]")
    Local $aCall = DllCall($PSAPI, "int", "EnumProcessModules", "ptr", $hProcess, "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($Modules), "dword", DllStructGetSize($Modules), "dword*", 0)
    If $aCall[4] > 0 Then
        Local $iModnum = $aCall[4] / 4
        Local $aTemp
        For $i = 1 To $iModnum
            $aTemp = DllCall($PSAPI, "dword", "GetModuleBaseNameW", "ptr", $hProcess, "ptr", Ptr(DllStructGetData($Modules, 1, $i)), "wstr", "", "dword", 260)
            If $aTemp[3] = $sModule Then
                DllClose($PSAPI)
                Return Ptr(DllStructGetData($Modules, 1, $i))
            EndIf
        Next
    EndIf

    DllClose($PSAPI)
    Return SetError(-1, 0, 0)


EndFunc   ;==>_MemoryModuleGetBaseAddress
```